sending email from contact form google sheet
tryed to acheive

send email to both receiver and sender email adress or atleast send email to receiver with all data entered in form(like: name,email,phone,message,file).
here is image for email with all data submitted in form.

whats not working

i tryed to add feature like if user submit form the email send to emailaddress of receiver as well sender(copy of email) with all entered data in form(like: name,email,phone,message,file). but didnt worked, here is code:



MailApp.sendEmail({ to: receiver_email@gmail.com, to: formObject.email,
 subject: "message submited",
 body: "name,email,phone,messsage,file" });




also i successfully wrote code for timedelay loading animation between, 'after submiting form and showing success message' (i am using swal.fire()to show success message)but unable to add this seperated css and codes in single html in google appscript.



$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#myform").on("submit", function(){
    $("#preloder").fadeIn();
  });//submit
});//document ready
/* Preloder */

#preloder {
    display: none;
    position: fixed;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    z-index: 999999;
    /* background: #000; */
    background: #ffffff;
}

.loader {
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    margin-top: -20px;
    margin-left: -20px;
    border-radius: 60px;
    animation: loader 0.8s linear infinite;
    -webkit-animation: loader 0.8s linear infinite;
}

@keyframes loader {
    0% {
        -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);
        transform: rotate(0deg);
        border: 4px solid #056d4d;      
        /* border: 4px solid #f44336; */
        border-left-color: transparent;
    }
    50% {
        -webkit-transform: rotate(180deg);
        transform: rotate(180deg);
        border: 4px solid #056d4d;
        /* border: 4px solid #673ab7; */
        border-left-color: transparent;
    }
    100% {
        -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg);
        transform: rotate(360deg);
        border: 4px solid #056d4d;
        border-left-color: transparent;
    }
}

@-webkit-keyframes loader {
    0% {
        -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);
        border: 4px solid #056d4d;
        border-left-color: transparent;
    }
    50% {
        -webkit-transform: rotate(180deg);
        border: 4px solid #056d4d;
        border-left-color: transparent;
    }
    100% {
        -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg);
        border: 4px solid #056d4d;
        border-left-color: transparent;
    }
}
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- Page Preloder -->
<div id="preloder">
    <div class="loader"></div>
</div>

<form id="myform">
  <input type="text" name="fname" id="fname" value="" />
  <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>



Here is appscript i tryed to add email sending feature and timedelay loading animation feature. {files made in appscript: (code.gs and index.html and library id)}.
library id
1CcBYkrGSeBRgphHUE92vWInyULOcJ1Ub6eFUR0_gI1h9I6whLjXtDA-P

code.gs


function doGet() {
  return HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile('index').evaluate()
  .addMetaTag('viewport', 'width=device-width, initial-scale=1')
  .setXFrameOptionsMode(HtmlService.XFrameOptionsMode.ALLOWALL)
}

var url = '#'
var sh = 'file1'
var folderId = '#'

function processForm(formdata) {
  var superscript = SuperScript.initSuper(url, sh);
  var formObject = {};
  formdata.forEach(element => formObject[element.name] = element.value);
  formdata.forEach(element => formObject[element.message] = element.value);
  formdata.forEach(element => formObject[element.email] = element.value);
  formdata.forEach(element => formObject[element.phone] = element.value);

  var f = formdata.find(({ name }) => name == "myfile");
  var file = (f && f.value?.name && f.value?.data) ? superscript.uploadFile(folderId, formObject.myfile.data, formObject.myfilename) : "";
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl(url);
  var ws = ss.getSheets()[0];
  ws.appendRow([
    new Date(),
    formObject.name,
    "'" + formObject.message,
    formObject.email,
    formObject.phone,
    file && file.getUrl()
  ]);

}



index.html


<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js"
        integrity="sha512-894YE6QWD5I59HgZOGReFYm4dnWc1Qt5NtvYSaNcOP+u1T9qYdvdihz0PPSiiqn/+/3e7Jo4EaG7TubfWGUrMQ=="
        crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.5.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css"
        integrity="sha384-TX8t27EcRE3e/ihU7zmQxVncDAy5uIKz4rEkgIXeMed4M0jlfIDPvg6uqKI2xXr2" crossorigin="anonymous">
  
  
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container py-5">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-lg-5 col-md-8 mx-auto shadow border bg-white p-4 rounded">
                <nav class="navbar navbar-dark bg-primary">
                    <a class="navbar-brand" href="#" fw-bold mb-3>WRITE YOUR QUERY / MESSAGE</a>
                </nav>
                <br>
                <form id="myForm" onsubmit="handleFormSubmit()">
                    <div id="form_alerts"></div>
                    <div class="form-group mb-3">
                        <label for="name">Name</label>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="name" placeholder="Enter your Name here|" name="name"required>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group mb-3">
            <label for="email" >Email</label>
                        <input type="email"  class="form-control" id="email"
            placeholder="Enter your email address here|" name="email" required>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group mb-3">
           <label for="phone">phone number</label>
  <input type="tel" id="phone" class="form-control" name="phone" placeholder="Enter your phone number here with country code|" pattern="[+]{1}[0-9]{2}[0-9]{10}" required>
  <small>requested example Format: +919263943858</small>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group mb-3">
              <label for="message">Message</label>
    <textarea class="form-control" id="message" placeholder="Write your message here|" name="message" required ></textarea>
              </div>

                         <div class="form-group mb-3">
                            <label for="uploadFile">Upload File</label>
                            <input type="file" class="form-control" File="file" id="file">
              <small>For multiple/bigger file size please attach/share via google drive link in message section.</small>
                            </div>

                            <button type="submit" class= "btn btn-primary btn-block">SEND</button>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
  <script>
        function preventFormSubmit() {
                var forms = document.querySelectorAll('form');
                for (var i = 0; i < forms.length; i++) {
                    forms[i].addEventListener('submit',
                     function (event) {
                        event.preventDefault();
                    });
                }
            }
            window.addEventListener('load', preventFormSubmit);
            function handleFormSubmit() {
                var formdata = $('#myForm').serializeArray()
                formdata.push({
                  name: 'myfile',
                  value: myfile
                })
                google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(success).processForm(formdata);
            }
            function success(){
                 document.getElementById("myForm").reset()
                 Swal.fire({
                  position: 'center',
                  icon: 'success',
                  title: 'Sended successfully! Be ready we will contact you shortly',
                  showConfirmButton: true,
      
                })
            }
        var myfile ={},file, reader = new FileReader();
      reader.onloadend = function(e) {
          myfile.data = e.target.result
          myfile.name = file.name
          console.log(myfile)
      };
     $('#file').change(function(){
       file = $('#file')[0].files[0]
        reader.readAsDataURL(file);
     })
    </script>

    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/1.0.0/js/materialize.min.js"></script>
    <script src="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/sweetalert2@11"></script>
  <script src="sweetalert2.all.min.js"></script>
</body>
</html>




as I've been trying your code, Can you Elaborate what is in the var superscript = SuperScript.initSuper(url, sh); I'm not familiar with it.

can you give me the following details?
TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'getRange')     at getLastRow(Code:10:30)     at gssheet(Code:24:22)     at initSuper(Code:185:10)     at processForm(Code:12:33)

@LimeHusky Usually means sheet name is not configured.

@TheMaster, I think it's from the library of OP and there seems to be a problem.

@LimeHusky Yeah..OP set a specific sheet name in the  library... that sheet name is not accessible. Changing sheet name  should fix the issue. Only OP knows the correct name or you have to dig the library.

I already found it on the library parameters. @TheMaster Thanks!

@ank Ask only 1 question per post.

Let us continue this discussion in chat.

Sending Multiple Emails Using GmailApp
Instead of using MailApp.sendEmail() I used GmailApp.sendEmail(), I also added htmlbody to match the Contact Form Submission output.

Here's the change:
From MailApp:
MailApp.sendEmail({ to: receiver_email@gmail.com, to: formObject.email,
 subject: "message submited",
 body: "name,email,phone,messsage,file" });

to GmailApp:
  GmailApp.sendEmail(
    ["your@email.com", formObject.email],
    "message submited", '',
    { htmlBody: htmlEvaluate })

I have 2 Changes which are the Code.gs and added email.html.
Code.gs
function doGet() {
  return HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile('index').evaluate()
    .addMetaTag('viewport', 'width  =device-width, initial-scale=1')
    .setXFrameOptionsMode(HtmlService.XFrameOptionsMode.ALLOWALL)
}

var url = 'sheets-url'
var sh = 'sheet-name'
var folderId = 'drive-folder-id'

function processForm(formdata) {
  var superscript = SuperScript.initSuper(url, sh);

  var formObject = {};
  formdata.forEach(element => formObject[element.name] = element.value);
  formdata.forEach(element => formObject[element.message] = element.value);
  formdata.forEach(element => formObject[element.email] = element.value);
  formdata.forEach(element => formObject[element.phone] = element.value);

  var f = formdata.find(({ name }) => name == "myfile");
  var file = (f && f.value?.name && f.value?.data) ? superscript.uploadFile(folderId, formObject.myfile.data, formObject.myfile.name) : "";


  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl(url);
  var ws = ss.getSheets()[0];
  ws.appendRow([
    new Date(),
    formObject.name,
    "'" + formObject.message,
    formObject.email,
    formObject.phone,
    file && file.getUrl()
  ]);

   // The change starts here.

  var html = HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile("email");

  html.info = {
    name: formObject.name,
    message: formObject.message,
    email: formObject.email,
    phone: formObject.phone,
    file: file && file.getUrl()
  }

  const htmlEvaluate = html.evaluate().getContent();

  GmailApp.sendEmail(
    ["your@email.com", formObject.email],
    "message submited", '',
    { htmlBody: htmlEvaluate }
  )
}

Email.html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <base target="_top">
  </head>
  <body>
    Name: <?= info.name ?><br>
    Email: <?= info.email ?><br>
    Message: <?= info.message ?><br>
    <b>File</b>: <?= info.file ?>
  </body>
</html>

Sample Output:
Sample Output of Sender and Recipient.

Reference:

Class GmailApp


yes worked great wow. thanks.

please add this loading animation feature the timedelay between "after submiting form and success message. will be much appreciatable. i successfully wrote code but the code is seperated css and code i unable to implement all css and code in single html. or maybe any other ways to do so.

hi here is what i tryed it almost worked but after clicking submit the loading animaiton spining forever not showing success message but data getting successfully storing in sheet: https://docs.google.com/document/d/1EmRKkGITR1ru5jUJQkqplWMAZVN85doJT1H3_wkmrWc/edit?usp=sharing
please note: i wanted/tryed to add only in index.html and this shared google doc is editable please check whats wrong in code which creating issue.
